# Can't install fonts Windows 10

Tags: 64-bit, fonts

I'm not able to install any fonts.

Whenever I double click on the file I get this error:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wDJYFGG.png]

Whenever I right click > Install I get this error:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/c3Mavju.png]

And if I go to the Control Panel > Appearances and personalization > Fonts to try to install the font from there, I can't see the "Add font" option.

From what other answers were I needed to enable my Firewall, but it's already enabled. I tried disabling it but same result.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Where did you get the file and how certain are you that this is a valid font file?  Have you tried installing it on another machine?

Comment: Got it from a official forum where someone had the same problem I have, although in his case he was able to install the font, I didn't. I could not try on another machine in my home so I asked a friend and he was able to install it.

Answer (score 0):

As I (approximately) answered on the Windows Forum at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/cant-install-any-fonts-in-windows-10/b11a1ac3-ddc9-4980-9d0e-5c501ab08749

I had the same problem but discovered that my non-administrator status prevented the font from being recognized. So my simple solution was to log out of my non-administrator account, then to log into an administrator account. You might need your IT department to do this.

Then double-click the font, click INSTALL, and you might be good to go.

Afterwards, log back out of your administrator account and back into your non-administrator account.

I needed to do this even though I had been unsuccessfully inserting an admin password from my non-admin account (using my "admin finger" for the fingerprint reader). There must be some issue with providing admin approval in a non-admin account.

Comment: So you're saying this may be a local machine permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - I discovered that the font file needs to be on the local hard drive in oder to be installed. When the files were on a network attached drive I did not get the Install option when right clicking the file nor was I able to drag and drop into the Font option within the Control Panel, I would just get the international not sign (red circle with a slash) and no error message. I did have admin access though.